# How to preload images in one activity then load them in another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, android-glide, preload

I'm trying to preload list of images in one activity then start another activity and load these images into imageviews that are already preloaded in cache.

I have two questions
If I preload images in one activity, will they be available for load in another activity?
Am I doing the method with glide correctly or am I missing something?
Are there other more good practice ways to preload images?

I have tried `Glide` to preload images, but the images still take a long time to load in the another activity

```
Glide.with(requireContext())
    .load(imageStory.image)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
    .preload();
```

Then loading them into imageview in another activity

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(stories[counter].image)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
    .into(binding.storyDisplayImage)
```

I expect that the list of images that I have preloaded in one activity will load many times faster in another activity than if I had not preloaded them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone searching for the same, there is the answer that I found

I found a workaround using another library, that is coil. For me, it seemed much simpler and a little better in all areas compared to glide.

```
fun preloading(uri: Uri?) { //for preloading images in cache
        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(requireContext())
            .data(uri)
            .build()

        requireContext().imageLoader.enqueue(request)
   }
```

And to load images in other activities or fragments

```
binding.storyDisplayImage.load(stories[counter].image)
```

Comment: Things like tags for programming language, and a code you tried should be added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

i use it like this

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(imageStory.image)
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already tried this method, there is no difference (

Comment: I use this method while developing an application, it works. why didn't it work for you?

Comment: If you can find any answer, please let me know.

Comment: Did it work you preload it on one activity then load in another activity too?